# WPBakery Page Builder | Create custom element and align

Tags: wordpress, builder, wpbakery

I have created a custom WP Bakery element called "Custom Title." This element allows users to input text and align it. The alignment section should have a default dropdown with options such as "left," "center," and "right," as shown in the image.

[image: view image]

How can I implement this alignment section? Your advice would be appreciated.